# Tensorflow LSTM based RNN - Incorrect and Constant Prediction

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I hope someone can point out where I am going wrong with my RNN. The long and short of my problem is that no matter the structure of my network, the predictions are always along the lines of this:

[image]

I have tried 1, 2, 3, and 4 layers of LSTMs each with varying neuron counts and either relu or tanh activation functions. For the above image, the network was setup as:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, input_shape=(length, scaled_train_data.shape[1]))) 
model.add(LSTM(256, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(256, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(scaled_train_data.shape[1]))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss="mse")
```

The actual training of the model passes ok, without event:

[image]

My data is financial data. There are around 70k rows and I have approx. 70/30 train/test split.

Where am I going wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So from asking about and reading around, it seems RNNs might not be the best solution for financial / random walk data - at least with the setup I am using. I wonder if using averages might produce better results?

Anyway, moving on to Reinforcement Learning.